# Yii default project configuration issue for PHPUnit tests

Tags: php, selenium, yii, phpunit

I have a default installation of:

- Xampp (Windows)
- Activate curl extension: (extension=php_curl.dll in C:/xampp/php/php.ini)
- Yii
- Yii project (yiic webapp yiitest)
- PHPUnit (pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit)
- Selenium (pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium)

Everything went fine. So I do the following:

1. Start up Apache/MySQL
2. Tested if my Yii project is showing: localhost/yii
3. Open up cmd >> cd C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\proteced\tests
4. >> phpunit functional/SiteTest.php

Then I get this output:

```
PHPUnit 3.6.9 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\protected\tests\phpunit.xml

EEEEEE

Time: 25 seconds, Memory: 6.25Mb

There were 6 errors:

1) SiteTest::testIndex
RuntimeException: couldn't connect to host

C:\xampp\htdocs\yiiframework\test\CWebTestCase.php:63
C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46

2) SiteTest::testContact
RuntimeException: couldn't connect to host

C:\xampp\htdocs\yiiframework\test\CWebTestCase.php:63
C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46

3) SiteTest::testLoginLogout
RuntimeException: couldn't connect to host

C:\xampp\htdocs\yiiframework\test\CWebTestCase.php:63
C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46

4) SiteTest::testIndex
RuntimeException: couldn't connect to host

C:\xampp\htdocs\yiiframework\test\CWebTestCase.php:63
C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46

5) SiteTest::testContact
RuntimeException: couldn't connect to host

C:\xampp\htdocs\yiiframework\test\CWebTestCase.php:63
C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46

6) SiteTest::testLoginLogout
RuntimeException: couldn't connect to host

C:\xampp\htdocs\yiiframework\test\CWebTestCase.php:63
C:\xampp\php\phpunit:46

FAILURES!
Tests: 6, Assertions: 0, Errors: 6.
```

I have researched the problem, and it ***seems*** that it *could be* a cURL problem. Because this error is not know for PHPUnit but for cURL.

What is happening? I can reach my local website, and PHPUnit could not?

Edit: my php.ini: http://pastebin.com/9gPBNPmi

Comment: You can add your answer as a real answer, instead of just editing your question. Then this will question will appear "answered". Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: I have beneath 100 points, so I have to wait 8 hours before I can do so.. Thanks to stackoverflow! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit 2:

I can answer my own question. It is remarkable that you get new insights when you type down your problem.

**The solution is as follows:**

I Downloaded Selenium Server RC, and run it throught this command: >> java -jar selenium-server.jar

Then I tested the code again with the command: >> phpunit functional/SiteTest.php
It started Internet Explorer, but didn't anything, the command was waiting for a long time doing nothing.
So I had to delete this row from C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\protected\tests\phpunit.xml:

```
<browser name="Internet Explorer" browser="*iexplore" />
```

So it would run Firefox instead of IE.

Hope this helps someone.